# Necessary and sufficient condition for existence of a deck transformation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am considering the following problem:
$\tilde X$ path connected, $X$ path connected, locally path connected, $P:\tilde X \to X$ covering map, $x_0 \in X, \tilde x_0, \tilde x_1 \in p^{-1}(x_0).$ I would like to find a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a deck transformation sending $\tilde x_1$ to $ \tilde x_0$.

My lecture notes say that 1) $p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_1)) \subset p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_0))$ is necessary and sufficient. I know that 1) gives us a unique lift of p, say $\tilde p$, mapping $\tilde x_1$ to $\tilde x_0$ but I don't see why this has to be a homeomorphism?

In my opinion need the opposite inclusion of 1) as well to get a lift $\tilde p_1$ sending $\tilde x_0$ to $\tilde x_1$, and can then deduce by the uniqueness of lifts that $\tilde p \circ \tilde p_1 \cong id_{\tilde X} $ and thus $\tilde p$ is a homemorphism. Can anyone help me this this? Thanks.

Comment: Since algebraic topology is about modelling topology by algebra, it should be pointed out that the theory of covering spaces is well modelled by the theory of **covering morphisms of groupoids**. See expositions of the latter in Higggins' book "Categories and groupoids" (http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html) and my book "Topology and groupoids" (amazon).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It should be $p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_1)) = p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_0))$. You can find it in Hatcher's book.